# Nested loop in elixir

Tags: elixir

Given these two lists:
`l1 = ['a', 'b', 'c'] 
l2 = ["Foo", "bar", "baz"]`
For each item in `l1`, I want to run a func with each item in `l2`
something like:
`Enum.each(l1, &(fun1(&1, < each_item_in_l2 >)`
Is there a short way of doing that?

Comment: Read about comprehensions -> https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/comprehensions.html, it may help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can use comprehension, here's a quick example for iex:

```
for abc <- ['a', 'b', 'c'], 
    foobar <- ["Foo", "bar", "baz"] do 
  IO.inspect "#{abc} #{foobar}"
end
```

Comment: `l1 |> Enum.each( fn item ->  fun1( item, l2 );  end )` is how I'd phrase it